# Sending an object from javascript to an action method in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I'm trying to send an object from razor view to an action method

my view

```
    <section>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function saveExpense()
    {
        var expenseobject = {
            date:$('.txtDate').val() ,
            type:$('.ExpenseType').val() ,
            cost: $('.cost').val(),
            extra:$('.extra').val()

        };

        $.ajax({
            //   url: baseUri+'HomeController/saveexpense',
            url: '@Url.Action("saveexpense", "HomeController")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ obj: expenseobject }),
            success: function (result) {


            }
        });

}
</script>
<section id="form">
    <table width="600">
        <tr>
            <td>Select Date:</td>
            <td>
                <input class="txtDate" type="date" size="20"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Select Expense Type:</td>
            <td>
                <select class="ExpenseType">
                    <optgroup label="Room">
                        <option>Room Fare</option>
                    </optgroup>

                    <optgroup label="Mess">
                        <option>Monthly Mess</option>
                    </optgroup>

                    <optgroup label="Others">
                        <option>Bus Fare</option>
                        <option>Tapari</option>
                        <option>Mobile Recharge</option>
                        <option>Auto</option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Cost:</td>
            <td>
                <input  class="cost" type="text" size="45" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Extra Details:</td>
            <td>
                <input class="extra" type="text" size="45" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <button  onClick="saveExpense();" >Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</section>
    </section>
```

And this is my controller

```
   public ActionResult saveexpense(Expense obj)
        {
            obj.ExpenseId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Debug.Print(obj.cost.ToString());
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.expenses.Add(obj);
                context.SaveChanges();
                int total = context.expenses.Sum(x => x.cost);
                return Json(new { spent = total, status = "Saved" });

            }

                return Json(new { status = "Error" });
        }
```

Where it leaves in the HomeController.cs

when I inspect the response, I find

[HttpException]: The controller for path '/HomeController/saveexpense' was not found or does not implement IController.

Comment: Try: `url: '@Url.Action("saveexpense", "Home")',` You do not need to specify the word `Controller` that's for internal magic.

Comment: Thanks alot ! I'm really shy of my mistake :$

Comment: No need to be. MVC has a lot of "magic" going on with naming conventions. You get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying the controller name for the [**Url.Action**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper you need to only specify the name of the controller without the word `Controller`, similar to this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("saveexpense", "Home")',
```

Assuming the rest of your code is OK that should work.

Comment: I have done that before. That is correct though, you should not have `"Controller"` inside of the `Url.Action`.